# Update a Row Failed using Power Automate - Error: BadRequest

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am attempting to update an excel table by mapping data from a Sharepoint List.  It appears to be pulling the data correctly but the Action still fails.

Here is the Input:

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_excelonlinebusiness",
        "operationId": "PatchItem"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "source": "groups/9c178d5e-af1f-4a58-abe1-c9bbb8b82a21",
        "drive": "b!IYB5sGeARka0pqmmsZFjNYxCav5wmjhLrBJi2_jk_0XWhwFV-v4bQos_AMJjEalP",
        "file": "Shared Documents/General/MySite Files/HereWeGOAgain.xlsx",
        "table": {
            "@odata.id": "/drives('b%21IYB5sGeARka0pqmmsZFjNYxCav5wmjhLrBJi2_jk_0XWhwFV-v4bQos_AMJjEalP')/items('01DCW6CZMWNMDFIAAUHRD2ATH6WSHBSERU')/workbook/tables(%27%7B4C1941E9-7DA2-40B3-BBB2-3A473BE7FA86%7D%27)",
            "style": "TableStyleMedium2",
            "name": "Table1",
            "showFilterButton": true,
            "id": "{4C1941E9-7DA2-40B3-BBB2-3A473BE7FA86}",
            "highlightLastColumn": false,
            "highlightFirstColumn": false,
            "legacyId": "1",
            "showBandedColumns": false,
            "showBandedRows": true,
            "showHeaders": true,
            "showTotals": false
        },
        "idColumn": "Submitted by",
        "id": "Terricka Gregg",
        "item": {
            "Discipline": "Gas Ops",
            "Supervisor": "Wesley Summers",
            "Team-Shift": "Gas Team 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error from Power Automate:

```
BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON. Error while parsing JSON: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: @. Path 'message', line 1, position 71.'
```

I've researched the documentation for the action and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. The rows simply should be updating with information. I appreciate any advice with this one.

[image: Flow 1]

[[image: Flow 2][2]]

[image: Flow 3]

[image: Flow 4]

[image: Flow 5]
[image: Flow 6]
[image: Flow 7]

Comment: why is there an `@` in front of `odata.id` in the table?

Comment: That's normal @teylyn, that's a standard odata property name in PowerAutomate, you'll find it everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide screenshots of your flow and the specific point where the flow is failing?  It's not clear from what you've provided thus far.

Comment: @Skin - I've added some screenshots

Comment: Thanks, hopefully one last thing, can you show us the definition (screenshot) of the update a row step? You’ve showed the results of a run but would like to see the definition.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how you use Update a row in Apply to each? Judging from the error message, the error comes from the format of the value you filled in. What formula did you use?

Comment: @ChengFeng-MSFT : I've attached additional screen shots;

Comment: @Skin : Are these the screenshots you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Generally speaking, the name of the Table should be placed here, but you put the  record currently traversed. (Have you tried using a compose to output it? It seems to me that the data types here are inconsistent)
Since your path is dynamic, the table name needs to be filled in manually. We can check the corresponding table name like this:
[image]